# How can I implement Android servo control using WiFi?

Tags: java, android-wifi, android-hardware

I am Electronic Engineering student doing my final year project. My project is controlling two servos motors with an Android tablet (2.3) using WiFi.

What I set out to do is: when I enter the characters in my text box (A-Z), it turns the angle according to the character (180/26=7), each character symbolically representing 7 degrees.
I don't know how to interface my PIC microcontroller to my app. I am using the RN-XV WiFi  module for establishing communication between my app and the microcontroller.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to research more and split your problem into smaller chunks if you want to find answers on SO. Your question / problem includes UI representation, some sort of network protocol (probably even a way to discover your module within the WiFi network), a server daemon running on your module, etc..

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the P2P connection in developers.android.com, But coud not get clue. Does it in involved in Network service discovery.

Comment: Android's [P2P Wifi](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) will only help you if your module supports [WiFi Direct](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct) - I don't know whether that's the case but I doubt it. You may have to put them manually into the same WiFi network and do a [plain old (TCP Socket) connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95055/java-best-place-to-begin-learning-basic-networking) via the respective IP. Or maybe HTTP if there is support for that.

Comment: My module support ad-hoc network , when I read it about ad-hoc & WiFi direct, the main different between these two is that , ad-hoc work through the access point and WiFi Direct does not need the access point (WAP)& also Wifi direct is the extended version of Ad-hoc .And my module uses Point- to point protocol ? Does it mean I can use the p2p Wifi ??? Thanks @ zapl

Comment: I don't know. Try it. WiFi Direct uses a simulated AP with WPS on one device so it's roughly the same as manual connecting both devices to some AP. And if it works, you'll still need all the actual data transfer mechanism (raw TCP/UDP, HTTP,...). WiFi Direct will merely place you in a common WiFi network and can tell you each other's IP addresses.