# A simple client/server app

Tags: java, networking, client, server

I'm fairly new to Java coding (and to programming in general) and I'm studying a lot to catch up and having been through a lot of fundamentals (the language, OO concepts, Genrics, Concurrency,Collections etc..)and my future goal being Android programming, I'm trying to get started with networking (simple apps, just to get the grasp of it, and I know it's alot of stuff).
So, I set off trying to convert my simple tic-tac-toe GUI game (with a little bit of swing and Java2D) into a server/client game but I soon understood that it's a daunting task, at least without networking knowledge.
So, I know this may be a wrong question,or the wrong place, but please, could someone point me to where I can start to achieve my goal (it being a simple client/server application, I don't care if it's a simple messaging app or a useless minigame). I'm not interested in multithreaded servers or stuff like that, just the basics that can get me to code something actually working!

thanks a lot, please help me!

Luca

Comment: One google, top hit, https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/ .Got to learn google, mate.

Comment: Show your code for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[Java: Best Place to Begin Learning Basic Networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95055/java-best-place-to-begin-learning-basic-networking)

I've never done networking in Java, but my suggestion would be to read, read, read about networking in Java. Learn the appropriate libraries, learn how they work, what people have done with them.

First figure out *what kind of app you'd like to build* and then don't touch a line of code until you have a good idea how that type of app would be built, which means a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make a client / server app from Oracle with a working example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html